# How can sass be added to PATH in a nodejs cartridge on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, openshift

How can sass be added to PATH in a nodejs cartridge on OpenShift?

```
gears start
```

starts my Sails.js app but Grunt-contrib-sass fails to find sass installed using

```
gem install sass
```

even when ~/.gem/bin is added to the ssh PATH.

Answer (score 1):

if you use nodejs try:

```
   gem install sass

   ln -s /var/lib/openshift/53fe54c24382ec79e200017e/.gem/bin/sass /var/lib/openshift/53fe54c24382ec79e200017e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin/
```

or find one path in:

```
echo $PATH
```